# Why self-quenching (aka concentration quenching) of fluorophores is possible?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fluorescence

In some cases, increasing the concentration of a fluorofore results in reduced fluorescence, due to self-quenching (aka concentration quenching).

[image]([source](https://www.thermofisher.com/us/en/home/references/molecular-probes-the-handbook/introduction-to-fluorescence-techniques.html))

On the other hand, self excitation supposed to have low probability due to the Stokes shift between absorption and emission spectra in the same species:

[image](source: Pope and Swenberg, [Electronic Processes in Organic Crystals and Polymers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0195129636), 1999)

So what is the mechanism behind self-quenching?

Comment: Resonant energy transfer.

Comment: @CuriousOne, [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Förster_resonance_energy_transfer) they refer to FRET in different donor and acceptor species. The short paragraph about homo-FRET is a bit vague. Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: I can only suggest that you pull the primary literature. To me the explanations given on the Wikipedia page sounds like OK handwaving (e.g. the bit about the dipole-dipole interaction), but that's kind of all you can expect from there. Did you look at the original papers and the papers citing them? IMHO, in practice an experimentalist working with these molecules will always have to check the predictions of the theory against the actual results.